# Multiply 3-d matrix by a 2-d matrix with dummy variables

Tags: matlab, time-series, matrix-multiplication, economics, dummy-variable

I have a 3D matrix, X, of size AxBxC and a 2D matrix, Y, of size CxD. I want to do a matrix multiply and end up with a 3d matrix, R, of size AxBxD:

A = 30, B = 70, C = 300, D = 100.

The 3-d matrix, is a dummy variable which takes the value:

- 1 - in each dimension C at the instances AxB if (...)(and sum of all
  Cs = 300), different for each C.
- 0 - otherwise

X is defined as follows:

```
X = zeros(A,B,C);
for s = 1:C
    for i = 1:B
       for j = 1:A
          X(j,i,s) = data(2,s) >= beglat +5*j && ...
                     data(2,s) < beglat1 +5*j && ...
                     data(3,s) >= beglong +5*i && ...
                     data(3,s) < beglong1 +(5*i);
       end
    end
end
```

The 2D matrix, Y, is times series data.

My biggest problem is with the dummy variable.

Comment: It's not very clear.  What is inside `if (...)`?

Comment: the if (...) is a previous for loop which I used to estimate the AxBxC dummy matrix

Comment: you can get rid of all the `()`s, except for `data(n,s)`

Comment: i've submitted an edit to tidy up the question, but I still don't get what's being asked..which is a shame because there might be an interesting question buried here